# Query with Datatype

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have request to db

Here is okay

```
var allitems = ctx.Logging;
var filteredQuery = allitems.Where(x => x.Datatype == 1 || x.Datatype == 2)
                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();

for (int i = 1; i < filteredQuery.Count; i++)
{
    if (filteredQuery[i].Datatype == 2 && filteredQuery[i - 1].Datatype == 1)
    {
        TimeSpan differenceTicks = filteredQuery[i - 1].CurDateTime - filteredQuery[i].CurDateTime;

        items.Add(new HeatMapViewModel
        {
            Latitude2 = filteredQuery[i].Latitude2,
            Longitude2 = filteredQuery[i].Longitude2,
            Difference = (int)differenceTicks.TotalMinutes
        });
    }
}
```

In this row I have error

`var filteredQuery = allitems.Where(x => x.Datatype == 1 || x.Datatype == 2).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();`

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0019  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Datatype?' and 'int'   Traxgo.TrackerWeb.Domain    C:\Users\nemes\source\Workspaces\Eugene-Branch-Heatmap\Traxgo.TrackerWeb.Domain\Repository\ReportsRepositoryEntities.cs 566 Active

I can rewrite code like this

`var filteredQuery = allitems.Where(x => x.Datatype == (Datatype?) 1 || x.Datatype == (Datatype?) 2).OrderByDescending(x => x.LogID).ToList();`

But is that right?

`Datatype` field is Datatype type.

```
public Datatype? Datatype { get; set; }

public enum Datatype : byte
{
    Position = 0,
    Start = 1,
    Stop = 2,
    AddressRequest = 3,
    Alarm = 4,
    IP = 5,
    SettingsAck = 6,
    Input3Changed = 7,
    Input4Changed = 8,
    ActivationSMS = 9,
}
```

Comment: What is `Datatype`'s type? can you show how did you declare the `Datatype`?

Comment: I updated my post @S.Akbari

Comment: You can also use `.Where(x => x.Datatype == Datatype.Start || x.Datatype == Datatype.Stop)`

Comment: Why did you declare it as *Nullable*? Why not just `public Datatype Datatype { get; set; }`?

Comment: Indeed, use enums for what they are for! You do not want to compare to `1` (magic number!) but to `Datatype.Start`.

Comment: Thank's for help @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the `DataType` is `1` or `2` you should use the same type to make it comparable.

EF try to validate your operator and they can make comparisons between enum with byte type and the integer type.

When you change `2` to `(Datatype?)2` it means you parse `2` integer number to `DataType.Stop`

So your code should change to

`var filteredQuery = allitems.Where(x => x.Datatype == Datatype.Start || x.Datatype == Datatype.Stop).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();`

For readable and performance.